# Rename method in pydev not namespace specific?

Tags: python, methods, pydev, rename

Before I file a bug report I'd like to make sure I'm not missing something. If I have the files

refac.py

```
class A(object):

  def someMethod(self):
    pass

class B(object):

  def someMethod(self):
    pass

  def someOtherMethod(self):
    self.someMethod()
```

refac2.py

```
class SomeOtherClass(object):

  def someMethod(self):
    pass
```

And do Refactoring>Rename on `someMethod` in the `B.someOtherMethod` method, PyDev renames **every** method called `someMethod`, even `refac2.SomeOtherClass.someMethod`. My expectation is that it should only rename `B.someMethod`. I've looked around for settings that might affect this, but it seems that a global search and replace is the only behavior available, which IMO is very dangerous and makes method refactoring unuseable. Is there something I'm missing?

Ubuntu 12.04
Eclipse 3.7.2
PyDev 2.6.0.2012062818

Answer (score 1):

The method refactoring as it currently is in PyDev is pretty much unusable, but I think the reason is, that it's hard and might be almost unpossible to find all places where `someMethod` is called, because there's not much information about the type of a variable, so it could be `A`, `B` or `SomeOtherclass`.